# Removing url file extension in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I know this is a pretty common task and has been discussed here a lot, but I still can't get it to work. After doing some research I added this code into my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But it still doesn't work and displays the .html on my pages.
What could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional rule to externally redirect `foo.html` to `foo`. Have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't work. But it'strange. When I have the .htaccess in the root directory, my pages load like /index.html - and when I remove the .html it gives me this 404 error:                               The requested URL /web/index-en.html was not found on this server.       But when I remove the .htaccess completely, it still loads in the format index.html but when I remove the .html the site loads fine too.

Comment: see updated code, make sure it is in root directory of your site.

Comment: I realized another typo and fixed it. Can you try updated code again.